# Object Detection model using Vertex AI - how to properly pass input as image float32

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-vertex-ai

What I got was tensor flow model - .tflite file and .pb file + labelmap.pbtxt file with /variables folder. When I tested the model on my app, I used .tflite file and it worked well, but now I've decided to store the model on Server side. To avoid scaling, security issues I decided to go with Vertex AI.

I was able to import my model using .pb + labelmap.pbtxt file and also create endpoint to it = so far so good. Now, I do want to test it and this is where the confusion has arrived.

If I head to **DEPLOY AND TEST section** it requires to send **JSON** format to receive response. This is a lot different to what I had in my mobile app as I simple passed the bitmap to the model and it retrieved results. Well, that's fine, I guess I could encode base64 format image and pass it to the model, but this is where I cannot figure out how to do that properly.

Json example is:

```
{"instances": [{ "instance_key_1": "value", ... }, ...],"parameters": { "parameter_key_1": "value", ... }, ...}
```

What's the parameter_key_1?

I have not configured such thing.

I tried:

```
{ "instances": [ { "b64": "long_64_value_of_image" } ] }
```

and

```
{ "instances": [ { "image": "long_64_value_of_image" } ] }
```

And I receive: "error": "Failed to process element: 0 of 'instances' list. Error: INVALID_ARGUMENT: JSON Value: ...

Is there some easy way of adding additional configuration (seems that I'm missing something here) and pass simply preprocessed image (done on client side already) to this endpoint with ease (for instance passing base64 string and getting result?).

Based on what my .tflite model file says (I'd assume that .pb file is the same as that's what I used to upload model to Vertex AI):

[image]

```
Input Tensor: [<tf.Tensor 'input:0' shape=(1, 320, 320, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unknown:0' shape=() dtype=resource>...and

Output Tensor: [<tf.Tensor 'Identity:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Identity_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Identity_2:0'
```

How can I construct json, pass it as an `Image<float32>`? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/base64 According to the vertex AI docs...the JSON has a standard API.

Answer (score 0):

Try these as follows and let's see what happens.

JSON:

```
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "b64": "base64_encoded_image_string_here"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note:
In your case, where you mentioned that your model's input tensor is defined as:

```
Input Tensor: [<tf.Tensor 'input:0' shape=(1, 320, 320, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

You need to ensure that the 'base64_encoded_image_string_here' corresponds to an image with the correct shape and data type. In this case, the image should have a shape of (1, 320, 320, 3) and a data type of float32.

Python to construct the JSON request:

```
import json
import base64

# Load your image as a NumPy array (assuming you have it in this format)
image = ...

# Convert the NumPy array to a base64-encoded string
image_str = base64.b64encode(image.tobytes()).decode('utf-8')

# Create the JSON request
request_data = {
    "instances": [{"b64": image_str}]
}

# Convert the request to a JSON string
json_request = json.dumps(request_data)
```

Reference:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/explainable_ai/sdk_custom_image_classification_batch_explain.ipynb

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/base64

Comment: Hi, thanks for message. I mentioned in my post that I did try to send:

{ "instances": [ { "b64": "long_64_value_of_image" } ] }

But sadly, that did not work